# How to move the location of jquery validation error message to one box

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation lib. I want to show form validation error messages at top of the form.

Comment: I think you'll need to show us your html and javascript to get a solid answer.

Comment: There's an example of this [in the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).  Have you looked yet?

Comment: Most of the examples in the documentation do not work as described.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$().validate({
    errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
        $('#errorct').append(error)
    }
})
```

demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XHDvS/)

Answer (score 0):

Make a div with an id (for example #error) at the top of you form, generate an error message (submit.php), check if field is empty and load the error message into the div #error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#error', window.parent.document).html( function(){
$(this).text('<?=$errorMessage;?>');
});
</script>
```

edit: Saw this to late...you use the validation lib. ...hope this helps anyway...

Answer (score 0):

@Arun answer work as intended. Too bad i find it too late. I made this to make it work before i found this thread. Use it if the Arun answer do not work for you. Make sure subscribe-error div is inside the form:

```
if( $('#email-error').length ) {
            var emailError = $('#email-error').clone();

            setTimeout( function(){
                $('#email-error').remove();
                emailError.appendTo( $('#subscribe-error') );
            }, 10);
        }
```